# Variable to select schema in Postgres SQL script

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL script that contains `@` variables to identify the schema and I try to run it against Postgres.

```
CREATE TABLE @mySchema.MYTABLE 
(
    item_id integer NOT NULL,
    item_name varchar(50) NULL
);
```

It does not work with Postgres and throws a syntax error.

I know the `DECLARE @Variable` syntax from SQL Server. Is there a way to declare variables for Postgres? Or should I remove the variable because it is SQL Server specific?

Comment: Even in SQL Server, you **cannot** parametrize database objects (like schema name, table name, column name) in your queries with `@myVar` ....

Comment: You can use the `SET search_path` command to set a default schema and then run your queries without namespacing them with `@mySchema`.